# Modern query method for multidimensional js [array of arrays] other than nested for loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I have an array `[arr]` within an array of arrays `[ [arr], [arr1], [arr2] ]`

e.g.`["prague",50,14]` in the following arrays array that I want to check for:

```
[
 ["prague",50,14],
 ["vienna",48.2, 16.4],
 ["bratislava",48.15, 17.1]
]
```

and ideally I want to query this [arrays] array using a single parameter `["prague",50,14]`  to find out if my item **already exists** before deciding whether to **add** a new item **or not** to **avoid duplicates**:

1. check existing [arrays] array to ensure [arr] **does not exist**
2. if [arr] **not found**, add/push new item into [arrays] array

​

### current nested for method

Now the way I currently do this is by iterating the arrays array and in turn looping though each element

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (var k = 0; k < arr[i].length; k++) {
    if (arr[i][0] == "prague" && arr[i][1] == 50 && arr[i][2] == 14){
      console.log(arr[i][0]+", "+arr[i][1]+", "+arr[i][2]); // if item exists already
    } else {
      // code to add new item 
    }
  }
}
```

​which in itself is not ideal either as `if (arr[i][0] == "prague" && arr[i][1] == 50 && arr[i][2] == 14)` produces multiple results (see below code snippet)

​

### looking for a modern approach

Before I get flooded with "**duplicate**" post responses I just want to say that I **have** looked around extensively and read tonnes of posts here on SO etc about arrays, multidimensional arrays, many which were actually objects, and so on but I'm still none the wiser.

I haven't really found a good question/answer using a simple and **similar array example** so hence I've decided to create this additional post about querying multidimensional js arrays (not object arrays) in the hope they will aid code dabblers like myself

> I'm convinced there should be a far simpler **modern way** to do this
>   which is mainstream acceptable and **far easier** then my traditional
>   solution.

​

### tried to no avail

At first I thought I could do this using Javascript **include()** method e.g. `arr.includes([p1,p2,p3])` or jQuery **inArray()** method e.g. `$.inArray([p1,p2,p3], arr)` but neither seems to work.

I suspect it's because these methods don't work with multidimensional arrays like the one I'm dealing with here, right?

Perhaps I should look at a combination of the above coupled with my "traditional" method, perhaps it may improve code readability or perhaps there really is no better way. In any case I'd be grateful to see how peeps on here handle these type of multidimensional array queries.

​

code snippet

```js
// our array of arrays
var arr = [];
arr.push(["prague",50,14]);
arr.push(["vienna",48.2, 16.4]);
arr.push(["bratislava",48.15, 17.1]);


// params to check for
var p1 = "prague", p2 = 50, p3 = 14;
console.log("Check for Params: "+p1+", "+p2+", "+p3)
console.log("Expected values: as above ||\"true\" || \"int\" other than -1");
console.log("Our array of arrays:\n", arr);

console.log("_________________________________________________________");

console.log("Current nested for loop method:")
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (var k = 0; k < arr[i].length; k++) {
    if (arr[i][0] == "prague" && arr[i][1] == 50 && arr[i][2] == 14){
      console.log(arr[i][0]+", "+arr[i][1]+", "+arr[i][2]); // if item exists already
    } else {
      // code to add new item 
    }
  }
}

console.log("_________________________________________________________");

console.log("[Failed using: jQuery inArray() method");
var prague = $.inArray([p1,p2,p3], arr);
console.log(prague);

console.log("_________________________________________________________");

console.log("[Failed using: Javascript includes() method");
var prague2 = arr.includes([p1,p2,p3]);
console.log(prague2);

var prague3 = arr.includes(p1,p2,p3);
console.log(prague3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could stringify the requested array and the items of the given data.

Then find the item.

```js
var data = [["prague", 50, 14], ["vienna", 48.2, 16.4], ["bratislava", 48.15, 17.1]],
    request = ["prague", 50, 14],
    json = JSON.stringify(request),
    item = data.find(a => JSON.stringify(a) === json);

console.log(item);
```

Comment: Hi Nina

Gosh I completely overlooked **find()** (and findIndex() for that matter) which I'm sure I've made use of in the past. Although find() produces **undefined** if nothing is found, but this definitely seems an acceptable alternative :)

Looks like **stringify** converts the request and each item of the array (as it traverses?) to a string object. Now I'm wondering about potential performance hits when dealing with larger data sets or is this insignificant?

Comment: OK even though I haven't got a dataset large enough yet to test potential performance issues the provided solution is acceptable and I've already made us of it elsewhere. Thanks again for providing this answer.